# How to format a microSDXC card into Fat32?

Tags: filesystems, sd-card, fat32

I need to format a brand new Micro SD card of extended capacity into FAT32.

I've read that formatting SD cards of 64/128 GB requires special tools.

How can I format in my Linux machine an SD card of 64/128 GB?

I've formatted a 16GB USB stick with Gparted, does it work also with a larger MicroSDXC card?

Comment: Force running `sudo mkdosfs /dev/your-sd-card` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gparted should work the same.  However I have not tried it.  I use mkfs.fat as supplied w/Ubuntu 14.04 to format various microSDHC and 64GB microSDXC.